# How to pass an array through functions and return it back

Tags: c++, arrays, function, reference, pass-by-reference

At the moment I have the main function calling the GenerateMap function and the GenerateMap function does what it is supposed to but I want to pass it back to Map[][] in int main. There is also a runtime error that appears even though the code runs as it should.

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
> what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
> ```

Can someone help me with this. I am semi-new to programming so can someone explain to me what I need to do. THanks!

### **Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

string GenerateMap() {
   int MapDimension = 5;
   string Map[MapDimension][MapDimension];
   for (int i = 0; i <= MapDimension-1; ++i) {

      for (int j = 0; j <= MapDimension-1; ++j) {

         int random = rand() % 6;
         string x;
         switch  (random) {
            case 0:
               x = "D";
               break;

            case 1:
               x = "F";
               break;

            case 2:
               x = "P";
               break;

            case 3:
               x = "M";
               break;

            case 4:
               x = "L";
               break;

            case 5:
               x = "S";
               break;
         }
         Map[i][j] = x;
         cout <<"[" << Map[i][j] << "]" << "  ";
      }
      cout << endl;

   }

   return 0;   
}

void MoveForward(){
}

void MoveBackward() {
}

void MoveLeft(){
}

void MoveRight(){
}

void Player() {
   string Player;
}

int main() {
   GenerateMap();
}
```

Comment: `string Map[MapDimension][MapDimension]` is not standard C++ when `MapDimension` is not a constant expression.

Comment: Will your map always have the size 5?

Comment: @crashmstr I -1 in the loops so it works out.

Comment: @Nightdaw yes, saw that on second look and removed that from my comment, but it *looks* wrong on first glance and is not as "natural" as `<`.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Not always, just whatever MapDimension is set to.

Comment: @crashmstr Oh okay I see, ill fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @Nightdaw, what I mean is,  is the dimension known at compile time,  will it have the same size everytime you run your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly C++ has fairly weak support for multi-dimensional arrays, especially dynamic ones. It is often simpler to not use them at all and just use a single dimensional `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

But if you really want to use a multi-dimensional array and the size is known at compile time then one relatively simple solution is to wrap your multi-dimensional array in a struct and then return that from `GenerateMap`. Something like:

```
struct Map {
    static const int Dimension = 5;
    std::string data[Dimension][Dimension];
};

Map GenerateMap() {
    Map map;
    for (int i = 0; i < Map::Dimension; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Map::Dimension; ++j) {
            std::string x;
            // fill x...
            map.data[i][j] = x;
        }
    }
    return map;   
}

int main() {
    Map map = GenerateMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < Map::Dimension; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Map::Dimension; ++j) {
            std::cout <<"[" << map.data[i][j] << "]" << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Live demo.](http://ideone.com/uVFlDO)

Comment: @Chris_Drew Thanks! I haven't really learned the struct Map stuff yet in my programming class but looking at it, this looks really well made. Although I haven't much of an idea of what everything does, it looks like a class. I'll try using it. THanks!

Comment: @Nightdaw a `struct` is exactly the same as a `class`.  The only difference is that members are `public` by default.

Answer (score 2):

```
string GenerateMap() {
   // ...
   return 0;
}
```

Whoops!

This actually compiles, because `0` is a null pointer constant, which can turn into `const char*`, which can be used to initialise a `std::string` … except constructing a `std::string` from a NULL pointer is illegal. Hence the error.

I don't know what you actually intended to return from that function, as you never said.

But I know it's not that.

Comment: I am trying to return the array to int main. The version of the code right now was before I attempted to transfer the array to int main. I tried setting an array in int main to the GenerateMap function `string Map[][]= to GenerateMap()` and GenerateMap() returned Map[][] but that failed. I also tried using a pointer by making the array in int main and using GenerateMap(string *Map) to point it to GenerateMap(&Map). That also created errors.

Comment: @Nightdaw: You can't return arrays. Arrays are non-copyable. It's an unfortunate historical limitation of C++ inherited from C. Try to use `std::array`.